# Android design - appbarlayout with recycleView in FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have layout with AppBarLayout, and FragmentContainerView which might include horizontal and vertical recycleView inside it which all of them need to be scroll up and down
I don't want to Use NetedScrooview for FragmentContainerView, because my recycler including images, and it will not really recycle that way.

I've try many ways without any success. any idea how to do it?
(Attach one of them, for this example, the FragmentContainerView not scrollable, the whole scree scrollable only if i'm trying to scroll from appbar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/innerRootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <com.core.widget.HomePageHeaderView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white_50"
                android:contentDescription="Toolbar_toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title=" ">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/primary_200"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_phone"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_container"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use separate recycler views or included(I mean recycler inside recycler view)?

Comment: @Yuriy It's not must to be included, but it should be scroll together as part of the screen

Comment: Ok, there is two cases:
 1. Use ConcatAdapter to include two adapter to single recycler in clean way.
 2.  2. Use NestedScrollView. Because there no other options in my opinion.